# Why is oxygen sp2 hybridised in acetate ion

Tags: hybridization, atomic-structure

The oxygen atom with the negative charge on the acetate ion is said to be sp2 hybridised but I can seem to figure out how

I feel I may not have out much effort into this question so even a link to a useful website where I can learn how to find hybridizations for atoms other than the central atom will be much appreciated.

Chemistry is hard :(

Comment: The oxygen atoms in the acetate ion are **identical**. The fact that we draw them differently just reflects the inherent imperfection of our language.

Comment: Somehow I doubt that knowledge that *both* oxygen atoms are in practice rather **sp** hybridised won't help you. And that "are" part should be more like can be described using such approximation, if hybridisation is even used on occasion.

Comment: related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/9740/102629

Answer (score 1):

Oxygen atom in the acetate ion is $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridized because as @Ivan Neretin said in comments, both the atoms are identical because the negative charge is in resonance with the $\pi$ bond of the other oxygen atom and thus it has to be $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridized to show resonance.

[image]