# Comparing basic strength of acetamidine and 2-imidazoline

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, amines

[image: Structures of acetamidine and imidazoline]

My approach:

1. Conjugate acids of both molecules have the same number of stable resonance structures. So no conclusion from here.
2. Conjugate acid of 2-imidazoline will have negative inductive on the lone pair donating nitrogen by the other nitrogen atom. Since this effect is absent in acetamidine, acetamidine should be a stronger base.

Is the above approach right? Can ring strain affect the basic strength of 2-imidazoline in any way? Should I consider any other factor too to make the right comparison of the basic strength of the above two molecules?

Related Questions:

[Comparing basicity of imidazole and 2-imidazoline](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/76644/43333)

[How to predict the basicity of organic amines?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/42077/43333)